# how to add markers to map (not google)

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, maps, coordinates

how to add it in image that is from file(local system) not google. the coordinates should be fetched from MySQL. I searched a lot in but all the results in google map API but i want the image to be fetched from my system and markers to be placed according to the data on database

Comment: So you mean you'll be using static map which is an image from your system? this will result into a lot of complications especially when your going to map a coordinate of your image. Have you tried using HTML5 canvass?

Comment: i have tried it, but the requirement is that the image is static it should fetch the coordinates from MySQL and put markers on map and the table details should be fetched from MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I once done this in my previous thesis project. Since you'll be needing a static Image to map the coordinates from your database, I suggest that you could use Google maps Static Api, its not the usual google maps api being used but it is a static image of a map, if you can use a store the url of the map you would like to use instead of the image in your database, This is my best option if I will be in your position. Using this static api map will help you deliver this requirement you have at ease. Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/). Hope It helped you.

Comment: thank you i will try it and let u know.. thank u sooooo much.

Comment: is it possible do this as a web application

Comment: It is. All you have to do is to add the coordinates you got from your database to the link of your static image.